# ValueError: Cannot assign "<Merchant: anonymous>": "Store.merchant" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, python-3.4

I get an error while creating merchant object and store_categories object. I get an error 'ValueError: Cannot assign "": "Store.merchant" must be a "User" instance.
' I could not resolve an issue.

**My merchant object looks like this**

```
[
"merchant": {
            "id": 6,
            "username": "name",
            "first_name": "martin",
            "last_name": "lee",
            "email": "emailname@gmail.com"
        },
],
```

**My store_Categories object looks like this**

```
       "store_categories": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "product": {
                "id": 1,
                "image": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "imageName": "fishCutlet.jpg",
                    "image": "http://localhost:8000/api/stores/list/products/images/fishCutlet.jpg"
                },
                "name_of_product": "Fish Cutlet",
                "description": "Steamed fish minced with spices, combined with potatoes, shaped into cutlets and fried.",
                "price": "150.00",
                "active": true
            },
            "store_category": "FOODS"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "product": {
                "id": 2,
                "image": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "imageName": "chickenChowmein.jpg",
                    "image": "http://localhost:8000/api/stores/list/products/images/chickenChowmein.jpg"
                },
                "name_of_product": "Chicken Chowmin",
                "description": "Delicious chicken chowmein with spicy flavor and herbs that makes it hygienic",
                "price": "120.00",
                "active": true
            },
            "store_category": "FOODS"
        }
    ],
```

**My StoreCreateSerializer code**

```
class StoreCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer()
    merchant = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_long",
                "store_lat",
                "store_start_time",
                "store_end_time",
                "store_off_day",
                )
    def create(self,validated_data):
        store_categories_data = validated_data.pop('store_categories')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        for merchantKey, merchantVal in merchant_data.items():
            try:
                user = User.objects.create(username=merchantVal)
                merchant,created = Merchant.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                validated_data['merchant']=merchant
                store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)
                for store_categories in store_categories_data:
                    store_categories, created = StoreCategory.objects.get_or_create(pan_number=store_categories['pan_number'])
                    store_categories.product.store = store
                    store_categories.save()
                return store
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise NotFound('not found')
```

Comment: Error is occurring because you are assigning a `AnonymousUser` instance to a `User` ForeignKey(looks like) Field i.e. `merchant`.  You must be logged-in to get a `User` instance or either provide that manually.

Comment: how can i pass value to get_or_create() in StoreCategory.objects.get_or_create() as store_categories_data has such  orderDict store_categories_data OrderedDict([('product', OrderedDict([('image', OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: grocery.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])), ('name_of_product', 'des'), ('description', 'des'), ('price', Decimal('222')), ('active', True)])), ('store_category', 'GROCERY')])

Comment: @KapilSachdev i solved user part but i am stumbling on creating store_category object with such type store_categories_data OrderedDict([('product', OrderedDict([('image', OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: grocery.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])), ('name_of_product', 'des'), ('description', 'des'), ('price', Decimal('222')), ('active', True)])), ('store_category', 'GROCERY')])